# CSS3/HTML5 Responsive images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to use different sized images depending on the webpage size. 
For example, my images has two different sizes:

```
<img src="images/img1.jpg" data-big="images/img1.jpg" data-small="images/img1small.jpg" alt=""></img>
```

The data-small image has a width of 100px.

```
@media (max-width:600px) {
    img[data-small] {
        content: attr(data-small, url); <-- not working
       /*width:10px;*/ <-- this would work
    }
}
```

I testet it on Firefox 37.0.1, Chrome 42.0.2311.90 m and IE 11

If I resize the browser to a very small width (< 600px), the image is still the same.

Comment: Isn't this what the [HTML5 picture](http://html5hub.com/html5-picture-element/) element is designed to solve? Or [srcset](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/)?

Comment: @ChristianVarga: YES, but actually there is also a lack of support [look at this](http://caniuse.com/#search=picture)

Comment: Than set the `width:100%` and `height:auto;`.

Comment: `content` is a property of pseudoelements. and Images are self-closing elements so they have not psuedoelements allowed

Answer (score 2):

content attr is used in :before and :after selectror. How ever you can use media query.

```
<img src="images/img1.jpg" class="big_image" alt="">
<img src="images/img1small.jpg" class="small_image" alt="">
```

and the css will be

```
@media (max-width:600px) {
    .small_image{ display:block }
    .big_image{ display:none }
}

@media (min-width:601px) {
    .small_image{ display:none }
    .big_image{ display:block }
}
```

Comment: I use this way to but there is one disadvantage of this way: you have to load 2 images. For people who are using data on their phone they have to load one big usseless image in their case

Comment: @Vinc199789 if an image is set to `display: none`, it should not load. Can you provide an example where an image with `display: none` loads?

Comment: You can also use jQuey for this. Check my example - https://jsfiddle.net/Ljn27au8/  

Normally you will see a 400x400 image. Then Resize your browser ( make it smaller) and refresh the result, you will see a different image.

Answer (score 2):

Image tags work using the `src` attribute. In order to change the image, you need to change the `src` attribute, which you cannot do with CSS.

`content: attr(data-small, url);` does not change the `src` attribute. You're setting the `content` of the element to the `data-small` attribute, which does nothing on an `img` tag. As I mentioned, **you cannot change the `src` attribute with CSS**.

I'd advise using `srcset`. This will gracefully degrade in old browsers, and will work well in new browsers.

```
<img src="images/img1small.jpg" srcset="images/img1big.jpg 600w" alt="" />
```

Otherwise, user1936285's solution also works well.

Comment: okay srcset is working on Firefox 37.0.0.1 if I enable dom.image.srcset.enabled and also on Chrome 42.0.2311.90 m, in IE it's not supported

Comment: also not working on iphone newest safari and chrome. :(

Comment: @anguish Yeah, it's not well supported: http://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset. But that's kind of the point; it works in browsers that support it, and gracefully degrades in browsers that don't support it. Graceful degradation pushes the web forward, retrofitting holds it back.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use  CSS `background-image: url("image.png")` instead of `<img>`

Something like this:

```
@media (max-width:600px) {
    .container{ background-image: url("imagebig.png") }
}

@media (min-width:601px) {
     .container{ background-image: url("imagesmall.png") }
}
```

[WebPlatform CSS backgrounds](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/tutorials/using_css_background_images)

Answer (score -2):

Use:

```
content: url(attr(data-small));
```